# Keep containers alive using docker-compose on windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two services defined in docker-compose.yml file and expecting two containers up and running in output however the containers are getting stopped immediately. When I use the same compose file on Linux it creates and keep twp containers up and running. Is there any known issue with Windows?

I have tried using `docker-compose up` as well as `docker-compose run -dT <servicename>` no go.

my `docker-compose.yml` file is

```
version: '3'

networks:

  default:
    external:
      name: nat

services:

  awi-service:

    env_file:

      - awi-box.env
    image: awi-box:12.0.0
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
    - ae-service


  ae-service:

    env_file:
      - ae-box.env
    image: ar-box:12.0.0
    ports:
    -  2217:2217
    -  2218:2218
```

Comment: Are the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` of your images launching a long-running process? A container stops as soon as its main process stops.

Comment: Yes I do have CMD that runs long-running process. When I run with Docker run then container keeps on running but not with docker-compose.